# Opening a SQL plus spool file dynamically (before spool off)

Tags: oracle, file, sqlplus, spool

The screen reader tool (JAWS/CURSOR) for the blind, fails to read the results of a SQL statement in Oracle SQLplus. Spooling the output and having the spool file read in a text editor is working fine. But it is tedious to turn off the spool after every SQL statement to ascertain the results. Does anyone know a way of opening a spool file without turning off the spooling (without spool off)
Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate with the code that you have tried with.

Comment: Could be any SQL Statement (Doesn't matter). The Q is - Is it possible to open the spool file without spool off.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle buffers output to the spool file and flushes it periodically (every 8KB on my system, and I can't see a way to adjust that; according to [Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1317802337341) it's the O/S that actually does that), but doesn't do a final flush until you close the file (so if you run a query that produces a lot of output you can see partial results in the spool file, but the end is missing; at least in *nix). You therefore can't usefully look at the file until you close it with `spool off`.

In a Unix/Linux environment I'd suggest using `sqlplus | tee <file>`, which mirrors the entire session into a file and doesn't have the buffer delay. There seem to be Windows equivalents for [`tee`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29), but I have no experience with them.

I wonder if you're restricted to SQL*Plus though. Have you looked at using [SQL Developer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25259_01/doc.31/e26419/install.htm#CIHFHGFG) instead? Again I have no experience of using this with a screen reader, but they at least seem to have thought about it.